# Problems with my app on Froyo (2.2)

Tags: android

I have recently released my first app (a soundboard) and am now receiving complaints from Froyo users that while the app appears compatible, it does not work properly.

My app starts with a splash screen, then there is a main menu, which then starts the main activity, where there are 7 tabs. Each tab holds about 20 sounds, consisting of a textview and 4 imagebuttons.
Together with Ad banners, this comes up to about 500 views in one activity. Eclipse warned me that more than 80 views might be bad for performance, but even low grade phones like the Samsung Galaxy Y are able to run the app.

The min SDK I set for my app is level 8, Froyo and now after I got negative feedback and tested it, I found out, on Froyo the activity does not start.

Is there a fixed limit of 80 views per activity for Android 2.2? I could not find information on that anywhere.

This is the error I see in the Developer Console constantly:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com.cheftony.psychsoundfree.Nicknames
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What should I do?
I was thinking about modifying the main menu to start different activities based on the android version of the device, i.e. starting my regular old activity on any phone with Gingerbread or higher and creating a new one, where the interface is split up into several activities so there are not too many views per activity, which is a lot of work and basically would split up the app and double the work that goes into updating it.

Or should I just exclude Froyo devices? How important is it to still support Froyo today?

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of error (VerifyError) when I tried to call a method that is only in higher SDK version than my minSdkVersion. Even though I made sure that it was called only in appropriate SDK versions. The solution is to use reflection to access methods from higher SDK.

I am not sure if this is your case, what do you think? Are you calling such method?

Comment: My Soundboard contains several activities that are exactly the same in style or features, except for these aspects: this particular activity uses so many views and it uses scrollable tabs, but i already removed the tabs and still got the error, so i believe it is really the number of views causing this.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the number of views in this particular activity?

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Instead of the Tabs and Fragments I use for higher OS Versions, I split up the Activity into several smaller ones, going no higher than about 80-85 Views per Activity, made another Menu to pre-choose, which section the user wants and now it works fine.